# Getting error while iterating float variable in python loop

Tags: python, error-handling

I use `score` a variable to a float list `marks` but getting error of Code as

```
for score in range(marks):
```

Error as :

```
'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either iterate over your floats themselves

```
for score in marks:
    # score is a float now
```

or use their indices

```
for i in range(len(marks)):
    # do something with marks[i]
    score = marks[i]
```

or if you need both the indices and the values

```
for i, score in enumerate(marks):
    # i is the index, score is the float
```